# How can I keep a class from being inherited in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

In java, I could do this with the 'final' keyword. I don't see 'final' in C#. Is there a substitute?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're looking for the `sealed` keyword. It does exactly what the `final` keyword in Java does. Attempts to inherit will result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 6):

Also be aware that "I don't think anybody will ever need to inherit from this" is not a good reason to use "sealed". Unless you've got a specific need to ensure that a particular implementation is used, leave the class unsealed.

Comment: I disagree. Inheritance is often misused., and most classes aren't coded with inheritance in mind. So, unless a class was designed to be inherited, it should be sealed by default. Then, when someone inherits off of your sealed class, it might force them to think about it a little more.

Comment: I agree with Robert (i.e. I disagree with Mark). Inheritance is something which takes a great deal of careful consideration. For example, any time you call one virtual method from another, you are locking that implementation - changing the call to be the other way round can break derived classes.

Comment: Maybe I've been in the "framework" business for too long, but as far as I'm concerned, any class that's not designed for re-use and subclassing isn't done yet. I'm not convinced that putting "sealed" on every class is going to accomplish much in terms of making people think.

Comment: Actually the opposite will be correct, use "sealed" always and if needed remove it.  See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123773/is-oop-completely-avoiding-implementation-inheritance-possible#124591

Comment: There are a lot of ways to "reuse" a class besides sub-classing.

Answer (score 2):

As Joel already advised, you can use `sealed` instead of `final` in C#.

http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_Does_CSharp_support_final_classes

Answer (score 1):

The `sealed` modifier will do what `final` does in Java.

Also, although this probably isn't what you're looking for in this situation, marking a class as `static` also keeps it from being inherited (it becomes sealed behind the scenes).

Answer (score 0):

The `sealed` keyword would work, but still you can derive from the class using reflection IIRC.

Comment: you can also access private members with reflection. doesnt mean its a good idea

Comment: I highly doubt that you can derive from the class using reflection, either. If someone shows me a class deriving from System.String, I'll believe it - but until then...

Comment: Inherit via reflection? I don't even see how that would work or that the CLR would pay any attention even if you tried. Can you expand on that claim?

Comment: No kidding. Explain that one. How is that possible?

Comment: Apparently you can [write but not load](http://stackoverflow.com/a/156599/429091) such classes—you’re protected by the CLR at runtime.