# How can you inherit from a sealed class using reflection in .Net?

Tags: .net, inheritance

Before you start firing at me, I'm NOT looking to do this, but someone in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154698/how-can-i-keep-a-class-from-being-inherited-in-c) said it was possible. How is it possible? I've never heard of inheriting from anything using reflection. But I've seen some strange things...

Comment: Mmhh I think here's when reputation comes useful. The one that answered that question has 19 of rep ( as of sep 30 ) Chances are he does not know what he is talking about. In the other hand we have you, saying it is not possible. So, you should trust your self in this case.

Comment: :)  Kilhoffer(2,459) vs. dalle.myopenid.com(19)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without virtual functions to override, there's not much point in subclassing a sealed class.

If you try write a sealed class with a virtual function in it, you get the following compiler error:

```
// error CS0549: 'Seal.GetName()' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'Seal'
```

However, you can get virtual functions into sealed classes by declaring them in a base class (like this),

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    private readonly string m_name;

    public virtual string GetName() { return m_name; }

    public Animal( string name )
    { m_name = name; }
}

public sealed class Seal : Animal
{
    public Seal( string name ) : base(name) {}
}
```

The problem still remains though, I can't see how you could sneak past the compiler to let you declare a subclass. I tried using IronRuby (ruby is the hackiest of all the hackety languages) but even it wouldn't let me.

The 'sealed' part is embedded into the MSIL, so I'd guess that the CLR itself actually enforces this. You'd have to load the code, dissassemble it, remove the 'sealed' bit, then reassemble it, and load the new version.

Comment: I have seen an example where someone patched the clr itself. Do a search on Dinis Cruz and OWASP and you should find it

Comment: Security flaws where the attacker is stronger than the security system are not flaws.  "I broke into your building by replacing all the locks with identical ones, except they respond to Bluetooth commands from my cell phone."  The Bluetooth attack is irrelevant compared to your removal of my locks!

Comment: Amen, Jacob. Reminds me of an article I read that claimed Windows had a security flaw where if you booted a machine from your own device you could get into other users' folders on the windows hard drive. The author wasn't happy with Microsoft's response: "You can't expect security when you allow users unrestricted physical access to the computer."

Comment: Inheriting from a sealed class could be useful even if the only thing one could do would be to add interfaces.  For example, if someone was defining an `IDeepClone` interface, it might be useful to allow objects to be stored within it which were of a type that derived from `String` but included an implemented `IDeepClone` that would return itself.  If the half items in a nested data structure would be strings, encapsulation would increase by 50% the number of distinct object instances required for that data structure (since every string would need an associated `IDeepClonable` wrapper).

Comment: @alexmac Is this the example you're referring to? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Rooting_The_CLR

Answer (score 12):

I'm sorry for posting incorrect assumptions in the other thread, I failed to recall correctly. Using the following example, using Reflection.Emit, shows how to derive from another class, but it fails at runtime throwing an TypeLoadException.

```
sealed class Sealed
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
}

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      AppDomain ad = Thread.GetDomain();
      AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName();
      an.Name = "MyAssembly";
      AssemblyBuilder ab = ad.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
      ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");
      TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("MyType", TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(Sealed));

      // Following throws TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MyType' from
      // assembly 'MyAssembly' because the parent type is sealed.
      Type t = tb.CreateType();
   }
}
```

Comment: If you can't load the thing you've generated, I don't think that counts as creating a derived class... After all, you can create all kinds of messed up things using `Reflection.Emit`, but that doesn't make it so that those things are somehow now valid.

Comment: @OrionEdwards: That is what I wrote in this answer. It will not work, and I was incorrect in my previous assumptions.

Comment: +100, you saved me HOURS of research. This demonstrates that we can't inherit from a sealed class even when we build the child class dynamically. I verified that commenting out the `sealed` keyword on the parent class prevents the exception. For anyone reading this, you'll need to at least add `using System.Reflection.Emit;` and `using System.Threading;` to the top. I'm still looking for a way to modify non-virtual sealed class methods at runtime, but it looks like even Harmony uses the `unsafe` keyword. I can't get Pose to work in Unity, and Cecil only modifies compiled assembly on disk :-(

Answer (score 1):

It ***MIGHT*** (would increase the size if I could).  According to the guys on freenode, it would involved modifying the byte code, using Reflection.Emit, and handing the JIT a new set of byte code.

Not that I **KNOW** how ... it was just what they thought.

Comment: That's the only way it would make sense. For the work involved, how the hell could anyone justify that?? It's just crazy.

Comment: you CAN'T legitimately justify it.

Comment: If you did that, then you wouldn't be actually deriving from a sealed class... you'd be screwing with the class to remove the sealing, then doing a normal derivation. That may be a valid solution to your problem, but I'm just sayin, it's not deriving from a sealed class any more :-) </nitpick>

Answer (score 1):

The other poster may have been thinking more along the lines of Reflection.Emit rather than the more usual read-only Reflection APIs.

However, still isn't possible (at least according to [this article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28783/1954)).  But it is certainly possible to screw somethings up with Reflection.Emit that are not trapped until you try to actually execute the emitted code.

Answer (score -3):

Create a new class called GenericKeyValueBase

put this in it

```
  public class GenericKeyValueBase<TKey,TValue>
    {
        public TKey Key;
        public TValue Value;

        public GenericKeyValueBase(TKey ItemKey, TValue ItemValue)
        {
            Key = ItemKey;
            Value = ItemValue;
        }
    }
```

And inherit from that plus you can add additional extension methods for Add/Remove (AddAt and RemoveAt) to your new derived class (and make it a collection/dictionary) if you are feeling really cool.

A simple implentation example where you would use a normal System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair for a base, but instead can use the above code

```
  class GenericCookieItem<TCookieKey, TCookieValue> : GenericKeyValueBase<TCookieKey,TCookieValue>
    {
        public GenericCookieItem(TCookieKey KeyValue, TCookieValue ItemValue) : base(KeyValue, ItemValue)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to inheriting from sealed classes.

Comment: The sealed classes which implement the above would now the ability to be augmented with a TCookieKey/Value objects for a pseudo extensibility. The method could even be hidden in the base class...