# Virtual methods without body in a sealed  class

Tags: c#, .net, virtual, abstract, sealed

When I try to run the following code it errors.

```
private sealed class ReqHandler 
{
    public ReqHandler(object @object, IntPtr method);

    public virtual IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(object[] args, AsyncCallback callback, object @object);

    public virtual d0 EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result);

    public virtual d0 Invoke(object[] args);
}
```

The error that I get is.

> HB_Auth.AuthImpl.ReqHandler.ReqHandler(object, IntPtr)' must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial (CS0501)
>   (HB_Auth.Patched)
>
> New virtual member `HB_Auth.AuthImpl.ReqHandler.BeginInvoke(object[], AsyncCallback,
>   object)' is declared in a sealed class`HB_Auth.AuthImpl.ReqHandler'
>   (CS0549) (HB_Auth.Patched)

Comment: C# is not C++: in C# the implementation goes into the class declaration.

Comment: Two problems: virtual methods still need an implementation, and sealed classes cannot have virtual members.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a 'basic C# program'. It's not basic, it's not (valid) C#, and it's not a program.

Comment: Are your errors compile errors or warnings? You can use pragma to disable warnings which you find annoying before a code block and then to turn them back on again.. Additionally see my comments below for possible options on how to move the virtual member but keep the declaration.

[MSDN]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x74w198a.aspx

Comment: Your real solution is to pick up some basic C# tutorials.  Our user base can't really teach you how to code C#.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler error says it all:
You have declared methods, but they do not have a body.  So, either give them a body, ar mark them as abstract.
However, as I see that your class is private and sealed, making them abstract is a no-go, as your class is sealed, so nobody can inherit from it.

But, the code that you've pasted, looks like decompiled code ?

Comment: it is decompiled not all of it just this bit is because i lost part of the source files when i lost my memory stick

Answer (score 3):

- You can't have virtual members in a sealed class.

**CS0549 Error:**

> A sealed class cannot be used as a base class, and a virtual method has to be implemented in a derived class, which is a contradiction.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exaxze9s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

- The functions need to be implemented:

**CS0501 Error:**

> Non `abstract` methods must have implementations.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwze7c55%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

You probably want to make the class `protected`,and  the `virtual` functions `abstract`

Comment: tried that then it caused lots more errors

Comment: @user1388129. What are you trying to do? it looks like googling C# abstract tutorial could help you.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: constructors need a body. You can't just declare a constructor, you need to define it. You can use an empty constructor if you want:

```
public ReqHandler(object @object, IntPtr method) {}
```

Second problem: you made a sealed class, but have virtual methods. Virtual methods exist solely for overriding in classes extending this class, but you can't extend a sealed class, therefore the error. You need to either define those methods, or unseal the class (in which case, you'll need to extend it to do anything useful).

Comment: (nitpicking) virtual methods exist for a _possibility_ for late binding, i.e., possibility to be overridden: no problem if no dreived class overrides them.

Comment: @Vlad True. But there still has to be a possibility, which there isn't with a sealed class. Damn nitpickers. ;P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155087/how-can-you-inherit-from-a-sealed-class-using-reflection-in-net

Research says...

"You can sneak virtual members into a sealed class by inserting them into a base class"

Comment: My objection was only against "Virtual methods exist solely for overriding", and not for the rest :-P