# Inheritance vs varying instances?

Tags: c#, java, oop

If I were modelling various brands of cars would I use an inheritance hierarchy, or just varying constructor parameters?

What is the general rule for whether to relate objects using inheritance, or just by re-using the same class?

For cars I could just do something like new Car("Porsche","991","3.8") or I could have an overall abstract Car superclass, with abstract subclass manufacturers like "Porsche" and then possibly a class for each model of Porsche?

Comment: An explanation from the down-voter and closer would be appreciated....

Comment: The close-voter (not me) said "not constructive".

Comment: When will people stop teaching software development with stupid analogies, such as Cars or Animals? The general rule is: "you will most probably never write a class called Animal or Car". Discussing a real world example is much more productive. And, oh, I'm actually more curious from the up-voters.

Comment: @Bruno Reis: In my opinion, cars or animals (or this kind of things) are the perfect example because they are a very basic concept for our minds but not in the reality, so it helps understand how a trivial thing can be decomposed to something with a compact structure.

Comment: @BrunoReis, you must be one of those people who, when trying to explain something to someone, fails because you didnt explain the basic concept and the listener spent as much time trying to understand the setup of your example as much as the concept they wanted to learn. Basic examples allow people to concentrate absorbing the thing they wanted to learn and not the particular "framework" used to explain it.

Comment: @user997112, it is a shame we don't know each other; you would be surprised on how effective are my ways of teaching using extremely simple, precise, real-word examples (assuming I'm teaching smart people).

Comment: I suggest reading a book or three on OOP and use Stack Overflow for when you have an actual programming problem to solve instead of general theories to discuss.

Comment: @Anthony, why is it ok the following post doesn't contain an actual problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123773/is-oop-completely-avoiding-implementation-inheritance-possible?rq=1

Comment: That question is from 2008, and in 2008, *things were different.* In 2012, we have tighter standards. And in 2012, we also have more sites on the Stack Exchange network where 2008 questions might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a few properties that are shared by all cars (or methods that act on the object), and then unique properties (or methods) for each make/model, then you'd want to use inheritance. Otherwise, just varying instances are fine.

Let's just say you want these properties for all cars:

- Make
- Model
- Year
- Number of doors

In this case, you wouldn't want to create a class hierarchy, because it doesn't buy you anything.

Instead, if you had two "types" of cars: regular and race-car, and only the race-car could enable Nitrous Oxide (presumably a method that does this), you'd want a Car class, with RegularCar and RaceCar inheriting from it.

If you're just afraid of having to pass the same parameters to your constructor all the time, you can create static methods that call the constructor on your behalf. This is known as the [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

PS: my example really just came off the top of my head. But I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to say :)

Answer (score 3):

Creating subclasses is about [managing complexity](http://talkingaboutsoftwaredesign.wordpress.com/#Managing%20Complexity) and splitting your problem into smaller and more simpler distinct and non overlapping cases. If you had to solve some problems for all the cars, and you think, this problem behave "specially" for Porsche because they have an extra backup engine that normal cars don't have, you could create something like

```
PorscheCar : Car
{
    Engine engine;
    Engine backupEngine;
}
NonPorscheCar : Car
{
    Engine singleEngine;
}
```

So after you've decided to create a class that will solve a problem, if you detect multiple cases inside that problem, that you can, and decide to solve independently, you can create a subclass for each one of those. You can always solve every problem without using subclasses. The issue with that, is that I'll be a lot difficult to properly manage and organize the code if you don't create subclasses when you should create them.

You have to be careful to select what each problems each object or classes solve. If you want your Porsche to be printed like ***Porsche*** and normal cars without the ***, it doesn't mean that Porsche "behaves" different, and you need to create a specific subclass. What actually behaves differently is how you print Porsche, so you should create something like:

```
Car
{
    Brand brand;
}
CarPrinter
{
    Car carToPrint;
    static CreatePrinter(Car car)
    {
        return car.Brand() == PorscheBrand() ? new PorscheCarPrinter(car) : new DefaultCarPrinter(car);
    }
}
PorscheCarPrinter
{
    Print();
}
DefaultCarPrinter
{
    Print();
}
```

So the problem that is splited into two cases is printing cars, not modeling cars per se.

In a more abstract way, you should create a class to model each concept of your domain. When you detect that the responsibility modeled and solved by a specific concept of that domain is complex, and you want to split it into smaller and distinct and non overlapping cases, then you should create a subclass for each of those smaller problems.

In your particular case, I don't know your entire problem, but it's highly unlikely you need to create subclasses for each brand of cars, since they are usually a single concept with just a single case to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the single class approach is that you are stuck with the same instance variables and methods for all the different kinds of `Car`s.

For example, an Autobot might have a `transform()` method that most other cars would not have.

I mean, in theory you could define a `transform()` method for all `Car`s and have cars that don't support it throw an exception. But that's a much messier design than using inheritance.

Inheritance also gives you do fancy things like polymorphism. So for example, each car might have a `parallelPark()` method. But fancier cars might have an automated parallel parking mechanism that differs from all other cars. In that case, you simply override the `parallelPark()` method and Java will pick the right method.

Comment: So is the rule only use inheritance if they want to share methods/attributes?

Comment: There isn't a catch-all "rule" for when to use inheritance. I would say use inheritance when it simplifies the structure of your program. Some people go overboard with inheritance and introduce too many layers of abstraction in their applications. It ultimately comes down to your best judgement.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that depends on how much logic is dependent on those properties like manufacturer and model.  If it's none, it makes sense to do `new Car("Porsche","991","3.8")`, since the manufacturer and model are just properties.  However, if the manufacturer and model define a single set of other properties, or of logic, then classes might make sense.  That way instead of passing `new Car("Porsche","991","3.8", gearingRatios, topSpeed, price, etc)` every time you want a Porsche 991, you can just define a `Porsche991` class that defines all of those properties.

Or, expanding more on the logic portion of it, if `Porsche` and `Volkswagen` cars would have very different logic in, say, the `Accelerate()` method, then instead of having one `Accelerate()` with a not-extensible switch/case method, you can use inheritance.  Or if `Porsche`s need a `Race()` method while `Volkswagen`s do not, etc.

It's difficult to generalize this to a `Car` example without knowing how you plan on using the `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

For a superclass like cars, the more appropriate subclasses would be coupes, sedans, and convertibles. Car models should be a parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "superclass like cars"? Where did this rule of thumb come from?

Comment: From what I have learned subclasses have to subcategories of superclasses, am I right? The person who posted the question explicitly stated he wanted cars to be a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [type object pattern (pdf)](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/dpa/typeobject.pdf).